# Auto dim missing from Huawei Y7

Tags: 7.0-nougat, huawei

Android 7.0 on Huawei Y7 model TRT-LX2, has an Auto dim feature where the screen gets brighter when out doors and dimmer when indoors. To activate, there is a checkbox with a tick next to the brightness sliderbar.

However, the dimmer have not been working the whole week. I just realised that Auto dim checkbox is completely missing. A call to the local support centre and their solution was to clear and reset to factory setting. Plugin to a wifi and do the Android updates. I dont want to go about saving all the data to do the factory reset.

How do I get back a working Auto dim?

Comment: Go to settings > display, and make sure that adoptive brightness is on.

Comment: In Display, there is no adaptive or adoptive brightness. There is a brightness slider bar. Makes it dim or brighter.

Comment: well i guess it's different on huawei phones. On a Moto x4 it's in display settings. It also appears under settings > battery. You can also search all settings for key words like brightness, auto, adaptive etc

Comment: Yes, there use to be a Automatic Brightness button/switch. It is now not appearing. Huawei contact centre say only way is to do factory reset. Will do that over the weekend if there is still no other solution.

Comment: i also have y7 prime 7 2018,  After doing some repairing auto brightness option is vanished